# Android - Workflow for Splash, Intro, Sign In, Main

Tags: android, startup

I am trying to implement the following workflow for an android application:

1. If the application starts up I want to show a splash screen (using
   this implementation: [Splash screens the right way](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/)) **only for
   the app startup**
2. If the application is opened the first time I want
   to show an intro (I consider using this library: [AppIntro](https://github.com/PaoloRotolo/AppIntro))
3. If the user is not logged in, I want to show a sign in activity
4. Otherwise I want to show the main activity

In theory I think I know how to do this. So the splash screen is not problem, showing the intro once is also no problem using shared preferences, also checking the login state is no problem using Firebase Auth. So gettig the different conditions is no problem.

---

**BUT where I actually have problems is how to connect the single activities.**

---

Should I use the splashscreen activity as some kind of bootstrap and start the according activities there?

Pseudo Code for SplashActivity:

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        showCorrectActivity();
    }

    private void showCorrectActivity() {
        if(introExecuted) {
            if(userSignedIn) {
                startActivity(main);
            } else {
                startActivity(signIn);
                showCorrectActivity();
            }
        } else {
            startActivity(intro);
            showCorrectActivity();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Or should I implement some kind of a flow where the main activity is the "master"?:

Start SplashActivity, redirect to main, check in mains `onCreate()` if intro has been shown, start accordingly, proceed to start login from main if needed.

---

Or a completely different approach? Any best practices?

---

I am having a hard time here, so thank you already for any suggestions!

Comment: just for the heads-up, try decompiling google login apk com.google.android.gsf.login.apk. it has got most of what you need.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion your approach is correct. You use the time of the splashScreen to decide to which activity you should go, so the user is not waiting.

The only case when i would not make it this way it would be if in your splash you have to call a web service asynchronously. That would make the start slow for the user.